# Blazor webassembly unable to add reference of library project inside the Client project

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

Hi I am working on a workshop where trying to add the my custom library in Client project but it is not referencing and showing warning as you can see in attached screen shot.

Could you please help

[image]

Comment: you can reference only Standard library

Answer (score 2):

In Blazor you can reference only [.NET Standard library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#code-sharing-and-net-standard):

> Blazor implements .NET Standard 2.1, which enables Blazor projects to
> reference libraries that conform to .NET Standard 2.1 or earlier
> specifications. .NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs
> that are common across .NET implementations. .NET Standard class
> libraries can be shared across different .NET platforms, such as
> Blazor, .NET Framework, .NET Core, Xamarin, Mono, and Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in my projects. It will be the dependencies of your db library. I had to upgrade my library from .net standard 2.0 to 2.1. then consolidate my packages.

Comment: If you get errors be aware some packages have and alternative libraries for 2.1, search the name space....